# rxjs map creating duplicate

Tags: angular, rxjs

In this map, I am trying to update the array on the index. This seems to be creating a duplicate. Thoughts?

```
const updateAirport$ = this.updateAirportSubject$
    .pipe(
        filter(airport => !!airport),
        switchMap(airport => this.airportService.updateAirport(airport)),
        tap(airport => {
            this.snackBar.open(`${airport.name} updated`, null, snackBarConfig);
            this.saveStatus = 2;
        }),
        map(airport => {
            const index = this.airports.findIndex(item => item.id === airport.id);
            this.airports = [...this.airports, this.airports[index] = airport];
            return this.airports;
        }),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 0),
        shareReplay()
    );
```

and then:

```
this.airports$ = airports$.pipe(
    merge(newAirport$, updateAirport$, uploadCSV$)
);
```

Comment: duplicate update? same index got updated twice?

Comment: duplicate of what?

Comment: when i run through this, the index is updated and i go from 165 array length to 166. checking the array, there is a duplicate of the item updated

Comment: Please see revision to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult one to diagnose as I do not have the complete solution, the below analysis will be based on some assumptions on my part, please correct me if wrong.

Your map logic is creating an immutable copy of the individual index here.

```
this.airports = [...this.airports, this.airports[index] = airport];
```

The output of this is then merged here.

```
merge(newAirport$, updateAirport$, uploadCSV$)
```

If the logic in `this.updateAirportSubject$` is based on a copy of `newAirport$` you are putting an immutable copy back into itself... if this is the case, remove the original index from `newAirport$` before the merge or modify the original without creating the immutable copy.

**Revision**

looking at this closer, I believe this logic is the reason for your issue, I am not exactly clear what you are attempting to accomplish in this line.

- You are creating an immutable copy of `this.airports` and appending a
  copy of the index on the end.

  ```
  this.airports = [...this.airports, this.airports[index] = airport];
  ```

You already get the index here using `airport.id`

```
  const index = this.airports.findIndex(item => item.id === airport.id);
```

And then use the index to do a boolean match on airport to make sure the index matches the emitted value and then append to the end of `this.airports`.

```
this.airports[index] = airport
```

**Example**

The below logic

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  index;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.index = this.array.indexOf(4);
    this.array = [...this.array, this.array[this.index] = 4];
    console.log(this.array);
  }
```

results in this output.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4
```